# Alternative to 'GNOME Character Map'?

Tags: gnome, offline, unicode

Is there a utility similar to 'GNOME Character Map' which allows
searching by name?

I tend to Google/Bing for things like 'unicode white smiling face', but that
does not work on an airplane ☺.

Answer (score 3):

The default `GNOME Character Map` actually has a search function: just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or go to `Search` in the menu. It allows you to search for words like `white smiley` and the reverse (the `☺` character, in order to find out what it is called and the unicode number).

Answer (score 2):

This one works great:

`sudo apt install kcharselect`

I don't like the Gnome char map since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16, as the Unicode blocks are listed in Unicode order (not alphabetical）and there's no way to change that behavior.  I hate it when they change the behavior whimsically and don't offer an option to choose from.